# Error:route.params is undefined Trying to pass paramater from a FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm kinda new to React Native Navigation and I'm trying to pass parameters from my array to another screen but I'm getting an error 'route.params is undefined'.

Class where I pass paramaters :

```
<View style={styles.container}>
          <FlatList
          data={FoodObj}
          keyExtractor={(FoodObj)=>{FoodObj.key}}
          renderItem={({item})=>(
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{ navigation.navigate( 'Root' ,{screens:'Food', params:{name:item.name}} ) }}>
          <FoodList item={item} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          )}/>
       </View>
```

Class where I receive parameters:

```
const FoodDetails = ({route, navigation})=>{
    
      const { name } = route.params;

return (
    <View>
        <Text > Hey{name}</Text>
    </View>
);
}
```

Here is the values of array I'm trying to pass

```
 const [FoodObj, setFood] = useState([
        { name:'Zeppelins' , image_url:'https://xxxl.lt/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/cepelinai-600x450.jpg',time:'3 hours', key: '1' },
       {name:'Kibins', image_url:'https://kibinaivilniuje.lt/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/kibinai.trakuose.skaniausi.jpg', time:'2 hours', key:'2'},
       {name:'Potato Pancakes', image_url:'https://assets.epicurious.com/photos/5761d0d88accf290434553ab/2:1/w_1260%2Ch_630/classic-potato-pancakes.jpg', time: '30 min',key:'3'},
      ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you are navigating to a screen with nested navigation, you have use 'screens' instead of 'screen' so this would be considered as a normal navigation change the code like the below code,

```
 navigation.navigate( 'Root' ,{screen:'Food', params:{name:item.name}} )
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out that fixed and error and showed a result that I wanted. This my first time ever tackling nested navigation.

Comment: Yeah I just had to wait a little bit before stackoverflow  allows me to mark the answer